# Generator matrix is giving non binary numbers

Tags: matrices

For the (7,4) generator matrix 
$
\
G[i_k|p] = \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
\end{matrix}
$

I should be able to put in all 4-bit words and get 7 bit words out. However, for example, the word 0011 results in :
$ \begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 1\end{matrix} * G = \begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \mathbf{2} & 1
\end{matrix} $

Why is there a 2 there? Is my generator matrix invalid? Is the code invalid?

There are other words that give 2's as well: [1 1 1], [1 1 0], [1 0 1]

Comment: Although the context of an error detecting code is probably clear to you, you've not said enough for Readers to follow your Question with clarity.

Comment: If you want to generate binary codewords then you should be working in $\mathbb Z_2$ i.e. modulo 2. So

$\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 1\end{matrix} * G = \begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}$